# PHP can (should) I array_map filter_var to $_POST

Tags: php, arrays, post, filter, sanitize

I just stumbled on this neat bit of code to filter `$_POST` data quickly:

```
$post=array_map("filter_data",$_POST);
```

I've updated it to the new version (after PHP 5.2) and I've got

```
$post=array_map("filter_var",$_POST,array(516));  // 516 == 'unsafe_raw'
```

Now I'm paranoid; this seems too easy.  So

- Should I *not* do this for all `post` data? (shifty nervous eyes)
- Is `unsafe_raw` the correct filter for generic `post`, `get`, or cookie data?

I should add I'm just trying for a general sanitizer, mainly to remove SQL injections.  If I have an email address or something I can filter again later.  Any ideas / suggestions / horrified stares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid SQL injection, *always* use the appropriate functions for your database just before plugging the value into the query string, e.g. `mysql_real_escape_string`. A general filter not specific to your database doesn't guarantee anything and will probably only filter too much.

For anything else, like email validation, use the specific filter on the specific variable that holds the email address.

Also, use the constant `FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW`, not its numeric value.

Comment: OK.  I've got an adodb layer that does the filtering at the class level.  Thanks for the tips.

Comment: (For those of you reading this later, I've moved past adodb, and now strongly recommend PHP's PDO tools, which do the same, but are build in to PHP.)