# PHP filter_input_array for $_FILES?

Tags: php, post, filtering

Is there a way to `filter_input_array` for `$_FILES`?

I tried

```
$ar = filter_input_array(INPUT_FILES, $args);
```

but it doesn't seem to be the same syntax as $_POST:

```
$pd = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $args);
```

And after quick check of the [Constants List](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.constants.php) shows that it isn't an installed definition for `filter_input_array`.

So, should I define it some other way? `DEFINE('INPUT_FILES' $_FILES);` likes to throw errors in `filter_var_array` like

```
Warning: Constants may only evaluate to scalar values in .... Line 2
Warning: filter_input_array() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given .... Line 37
```

Comment: what you want to filter and what for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use [filter_input_array](http://php.net/filter_input_array) on `$_FILES`.  None of the [filter types](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php) are suitable for file uploads.

From the PHP manual on `filter_input_array`:

```
mixed filter_input_array ( int $type [, mixed $definition ] )
```

> > ## type
> >
> > One of **INPUT_GET**, **INPUT_POST**, **INPUT_COOKIE**, **INPUT_SERVER**, or **INPUT_ENV**.

How/what exactly did you want to filter from the files?

Comment: that's not true, there's quite a few _helpful_ filters imho, like `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` for naming conventions, `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` in conjunction with `option` min/max for preventing large files, and importantly `FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY` for making sure that uploads are multipart

Comment: Good point about the `INT` filter.  PHP can and will already deal with maximum upload size, but not minimum.  As far as the filename goes, I would never trust the `name` of the file from the user; in this case `SANITIZE_STRING` would be helpful, or not use the supplied name at all.  When uploading files from the browser, if the enctype is NOT multipart, then the upload will not work.

Comment: I'm just trying to do a bit of future site here with my posts so I can keep the validation in my class' a bit lighter. Yeah I went through the docs and there are quite a few helpful things I found.

Answer (score 5):

try using filter_var_array instead to filter $_FILES .

```
filter_var_array($_FILES, $filters);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per php manual, There is no INPUT_FILES for filter_input_array.  I am not sure if a DEFINE would produce the answer you would want.

Take a look at the php manual for [filter_input_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php)

Also check out this post which may be of some help to you.
[PHP can (should) I array_map filter_var to $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731212/php-can-should-i-array-map-filter-var-to-post)

Edit:
You will not be able to define a new type for this function.

Answer (score 0):

Please see: [filter_input_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php)

You will see that INPUT_FILES is not a valid constant to be used.